# how can I force the for .. in to display indexes and not prototype members

Tags: javascript

I have this array and a custom prototype function:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'], indexes = [];
Array.prototype.each = function() {/* some code */};
```

// Now we try to iterate using for .. in construct:

```
for (var index in arr) {
   console.log(index);
}
```

In the console.log, we get indexes 0-2 and a key "each".

Comment: Don't use `for in` loops. Use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: don't use for in to iterate on an Array :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: That’s because `each` becomes an _enumerable_ property. You can try [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and make it non-enumerable.

Comment: I really still don't know why did the console.log gives indexes 0-2 and a key "each".

Answer (score 0):

you can use **forEach**

```
arr.forEach(function(val){
   console.log(val);
});
```

for more see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [this](http://www.aptuz.com/blog/looping-in-javascript/)